# $\mathcal A^{\circ}$ and $\overline{\mathcal A}$ of a set of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, matrices

> We define $d(A,B)=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}|a_{ij}-b_{i,j}|$ on $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\mathcal{A}=\{A\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}):\mathrm{tr}(A)>0\}$. Find $\overset{\,\,\circ}{\mathcal A}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$.

I'm new at this, sorry if this is a dumb question. At first I rewrite the set $\mathcal{A}=\{A\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}):\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_{ii}>0\}$ which is the definition of $tr(A)$ but now how can I find $\overset{\,\,\circ}{\mathcal A}$? I know that $\overset{\,\,\circ}{\mathcal A}$ is the set of interior points but how can I define those points? Are they going to be matrices? Same questions for $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$, thank you all, hope you can help me.

Comment: For $A^0$, you basically want to show that that for any matrix $A$ of positive trace, that "nearby" matrices also have positive trace. The easiest way to quantify this is by using the inequality $|a_{ii}-b_{ii}|\leq d(A,B)$ for each $i=1,2,3$. For $\overline{A}$, the easiest thing is to probably use the limit point characterization of closed sets. Which matrices can be obtained as limits of positive trace matrices? Can zero trace matrices be obtained as limits (with respect to the metric you defined)? Can negative trace matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your metric space $\left(M_3(\Bbb R),d\right)$ is topologically equivalent with Euclidean space $\left(M_3(\Bbb R),d_\Bbb E\right)$.

Second. Trace map $\text{tr}:M_3(\Bbb R)\to \Bbb R$ is polynomial, so continuous map.

Third. Obviously $(0,\infty)$ is open set of $\Bbb R$, so $\mathcal A=\text{tr}^{-1}(0,\infty)$ is open set. So $\overset{\,\,\circ}{\mathcal A}=\mathcal A$.

Fourth. Because $\text{tr}$ is continuous, $\overline{\mathcal{A}}=\overline{\text{tr}^{-1}\mathcal (0,\infty)}\subseteq\text{tr}^{-1}\overline{(0,\infty)}=\mathcal B$.

Fifth. If $B\in\mathcal B$, then $\text{tr}B\ge0$. So, for all $\epsilon>0$, $d(B,B+\frac\epsilon4I)<\epsilon$ and $B+\frac\epsilon4 I\in\mathcal A$. It means $B\in\overline{\mathcal A}$. $\mathcal B\subseteq\overline{\mathcal A}$, so $\mathcal B=\overline{\mathcal A}$.